# WSLでcodeコマンドを実行するとエラーになる

Tags: vscode, wsl

#### 前提

.bashrcにvscodeのパスを設定しています。

```
PATH=$PATH:'/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin'
```

`code .` を実行すると以下のエラーになります。
対処方法をご教示お願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\mnt\c\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:987:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

#### 試したこと

vscodeの再インストール

Comment: こんな記事があるようですが、何か関係あるかもしれません。[WSL2 VSCode Will Not Load After Ubuntu upgrade - Worked fine for 1 year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72850659/9014308) 他には19日前にIssueが出ただけで進展の無いこれとか。[Executing code within a WSL2 instance now fails #6883](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6883)

Answer (score 1):

コメントにある、以下を参考にしてgenieのバージョンを2.3にしたら、正常に動作しました。
ありがとうございました。

[WSL2 VSCode Will Not Load After Ubuntu upgrade - Worked fine for 1 year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850659/wsl2-vscode-will-not-load-after-ubuntu-upgrade-worked-fine-for-1-year)!